Trouble animating background color transitions with React, Redux
Please pardon me, I'm quite new to React
I'm trying to animate the background color to transition from prevColor to bgColor each time they get updated. I have the following so far
const Page = () => {

    const bgColor = useSelector((reduxState) => reduxState.color)
    const prevColor = useSelector((reduxState) => reduxState.prevcolor)

    return <>
           <style>
               {`
                .bg-fade{
                    background-color: ${prevColor};
                    animation: transition 1s;
                    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                }

                @keyframes transition {
                    from {background-color: ${prevColor};}
                    to {background-color: ${bgColor};}
                }
    
                `}
           </style>

           <main id='bg-fade' className='bg-fade'>
               <div className='container-fluid'>
                   <Gardening />
               </div>
           </main>
           </>  
}

Right now the color transition seems to only work on the very first time I enter the page, or on refresh. Subsequent changes on the redux state for the colors don't trigger the animation anymore. How would I get it to animate the transition each and everytime there is an update on the redux state?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Ok I figured this out after looking at some related post. The issue I was really trying to solve was triggering the animation to restart. Apparently after the animation runs once, its not easy to have to restart/reset. There are some hacks, but the cleanest way I read was to trigger a reflow.
I just added the following into a useEffect hook.
useEffect(()=>{

    // trigger reflow
    let element = document.getElementById('bg-fade');
    element.classList.remove('bg-fade');
    void element.offsetWidth;
    element.classList.add('bg-fade');

},[color])

This would effectively remove, use the offsetWidth to trigger the reflow, then re-add the class back to the element and the animation would run again.
https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
Restart animation in CSS3: any better way than removing the element?
